# Dynamically load dependencies in Backbone/RequireJs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using the Backbone/RequireJs javascript stack. What i want to achieve is to dynamically require the `Model` dependencies for a `Backbone.Collection`, after that `Collection` dependency is set.

I want to keep that `Collection` as much generic as possible and i want to assign different `Models` and rest urls depending on the main current context. The goal is, well, loading only the needed in a particular context.

```
window.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    initialize: function(modelName,apiRoute){

        this.modelName = modelName;
        this.apiRoute = apiRoute;

        if (typeof(window[this.modelName]) === "function") { 
            this.model = window[this.modelName];
            this.url = "./api/" + this.apiRoute;
        }
    }
...
```

The problem here is that `window[this.modelName]` dependency in the main context must be loaded before the `Collection` dependency.

Say the object `MainContext` needs a Collection:

```
// MainContext.js    
define([ 
     ...
     "model/Collection"
```

and inside `MainContext` i resolve the `modelName` variable needed for the name value of the required dependency for the Collection (e. '`Toys`'). If i `require(['model/Toys'])` inside MainContext, that dependency file will be loaded too late.

What would be the approach in a case like that? Appreciate.

Comment: I don't totally follow what you are trying to do, but you might be doing a premature optimization by trying to dynamically manage your dependencies.  If you keep it simple and use a static approach, then the RequireJS Optimizer should be able to take care of it all for you: http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing a standard Require.js circular dependency.  In other words, you have a Collection that depends on Toys, but some other module or modules are making that impossible.

The standard solution to this, which you alluded to, is to use the synchronous form of require, ie. `require(['model/Toys'])`.  However, it sounds like putting it in `MainContext` is the wrong way to go, because it hasn't been loaded by the time `MainContext` loads.

The way around this is to use the synchronous require in the place that *doesn't* need it at load time, which sounds like your Collection.  Your Collection needs the model, but it needs it at *run-time* (specifically when `initialize` is run).  If you change your code to:

```
window.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    initialize: function(modelName,apiRoute){

        this.modelName = modelName;
        this.apiRoute = apiRoute;

        if (typeof(window[this.modelName]) === "function") { 
            this.model = require('model/' + this.modelName);
            this.url = "./api/" + this.apiRoute;
        }
    }
....
```

the model should already be loaded by the time your initialize runs.

Hope that helps.

Comment: sorry for the delayed reply. this pointed me the right way to solve this particular issue plus taught me new term: circular dependency. thanks!